# Changing parent element using CSS

Tags: css, parent

When I have

```
<ul class="menu">
 <li><a href="bla">link</a></li>
</ul>
```

how do I make the LI-tag change a property (e.g. list-style-image) when  is hovered (a:hover)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can apply `hover` to the `li` as well:

```
ul.menu li:hover
 {
   list-style-image: url(highlight.gif);
 }
```

Note (Thanks to Andy E): `:hover` is not supported in IE6, and supported for links only in IE7. (See compatibility table [**here**](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/contents.html)). There is a workaround for IE6 and 7 named [**whatever:hover**](http://www.xs4all.nl/~peterned/csshover.html).

Comment: +1.  For IE6 or other incompatible browsers you would have to achieve this in javascript.

Comment: http://www.xs4all.nl/~peterned/csshover.html this guy has already done the hard work for you.  I've used it to good effect.

Comment: @Andy E Cheers for reminding me, edited my answer. @Mauro: Same link at the same time :)

Answer (score 1):

On modern browsers you can use `li:hover` but on older ones you would have to use javascript.

**Edit:** By the way, if you set:

```
a {
    display:block;
}
```

you can do all the styling on the `a` and you don´t need to style the `li`.

Answer (score 0):

You can give add directly into anchor element which is sub element of li element

```
li a:hover { ..style.. }
```

Or you can add a class for anchor to do that

```
li a.HoverClass:hover { ..style.. }
```

There is a basic example [here](http://css.maxdesign.com.au/listamatic2/horizontal04.htm)